# Visual Studio 2013 Community NShader

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, glsl

Stupid question but is there any particular reason why I can't install NShader on the Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition?

Maybe there's some documentation somewhere that talks about this or I'm just doing it wrong (although I doubt I can go wrong with double-clicking an install file)...

I haven't found any documentation on this, that's why I decided to ask this question here...so just in case I'm some special case here's the pop-up I'm getting:

http://i.imgur.com/s9oe8Oa.png

and also the install log:

http://i.imgur.com/t6dGEzQ.png

In case this is normal and there is some specification saying that they shouldn't work together...does anyone know or point me to somewhere explaining why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think NShader officially supports VS2013, but other people have gotten it working. I haven't had any install or usage issues with the fork from here:
http://nshader.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/IssamK/VS2013andUnityShaders